# not able to undertand cursors in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to fetch results in a `python2.7` appengine app using cursors, but each time I use `with_cursor()` it fetches the same result set.

```
query = Model.all().filter("profile =", p_key).order('-created')

    if r.get('cursor'):
        query = query.with_cursor(start_cursor = r.get('cursor'))
        cursor = query.cursor()

    objs = query.fetch(limit=10)     
    count = len(objs)

    for obj in objs:
        ...
```

Each time through I'm getting same 10 results. I'm thinkng it has to do with using `end_cursor`, but how do I get that value if `query.cursor()` is returning the `start_cursor`. I've looked through the docs but this is poorly documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what finally worked:

```
query = Model.all().filter("profile =", p_key).order('-created')

if request.get('cursor'):
    query = query.with_cursor(request.get('cursor'))

objs = query.fetch(limit=10) 
cursor = query.cursor()                

for obj in objs:
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Your formatting is a bit screwy by the way.  Looking at your code (which is incomplete and therefore potentially leaving something out.) I have to assume you have forgotten to store the cursor after fetching results (or return to the user - I am assuming r is a request ?).

So after you have fetched some data you need to call cursor() on the query.  e.g This function counts all entities using a cursor.

```
def count_entities(kind):
    c = None
    count = 0
    q = kind.all(keys_only=True)
    while True:

        if c:
            q.with_cursor(c)
        i = q.fetch(1000)
        count = count + len(i)
        if not i:
            break
        c = q.cursor()
    return count
```

See how after fetch() has been called the `c=q.cursor()` call and it's is used as the cursor next time through the loop.